# android setOnItemClickListener not working on one row but ok in other row, using 2 row layouts

Tags: android, android-listview, onitemclicklistener

Im using a listView that have 2 layouts for the rows on one row the

> setOnItemClickListener

but on the other row it doesnt recognize the taps,

```
public void initItemTable()
{
    listViewItem = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.listViewItem);

    listViewItem.setAdapter(new PhoneItemAdapter(new ItemPhoneDataSource().getItems()));

    listViewItem.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Log.d("mensa", "item index :"+arg2);    
        }
    });
}

//
    private class PhoneItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {  
    final List<RowPhone> rows;//row
    //data source, style
    PhoneItemAdapter(List<ItemPhone> animals) {
        rows = new ArrayList<RowPhone>();//member variable

        //choose cell! iterator
        for (ItemPhone item : animals) {

            if (item.getType().equals("item")) {
                rows.add(new RowItemPhone(LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()), item));                   

            } else {
                rows.add(new RowFolderPhone(LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()), item)); //imageRow!

            }                
        }
    }

    //delegate
    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return RowTypePhone.values().length;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        //con cast
        return ((RowPhone) rows.get(position)).getViewType();

    }

    public int getCount() {
        return rows.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        //cambiado con cast!
        return ((RowPhone) rows.get(position)).getView(convertView);
    }
    }
```

So the tap is detected when "item.getType()" is folder but not in item,

. Shall I include the code for RowItemPhone.java and RowFolderPhone.java?

so how to fix this tap problem?

thanks!

edit 1. RowPhone.java

```
public  interface RowPhone {
public  View getView(View convertView);
public  int getViewType();
}
```

edit 2. RowFolder.java .. the one that have the tap detecting fine:

```
public class RowItemPhone implements RowPhone{

private final ItemPhone item;
private final LayoutInflater inflater;

public RowItemPhone(LayoutInflater inflater, ItemPhone animal) {
    this.item = animal;
    this.inflater = inflater;
}

//text doble
public View getView(View convertView) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    View view = null;

    if (convertView == null) {
        //ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item_phone, null);

        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_item_phone, (ViewGroup) view, false);


        holder = new ViewHolder(
                (ImageView)viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.image_item), 
                (TextView)viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.title),
                (TextView)viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.description));

        viewGroup.setTag(holder); //pa q y como usa tag!
        view = viewGroup;
    } else {
        view = convertView;
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }


    //setup
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(item.getImageId());
    holder.descriptionView.setText(item.getDescription());
    holder.titleView.setText(item.getName());

    return view;
}

public int getViewType() {
    return RowTypePhone.DESCRIPTION_ROW.ordinal();
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    final ImageView imageView;
    final TextView titleView;
    final TextView descriptionView;

    private ViewHolder(ImageView imageView, TextView titleView, TextView descriptionView)     {
        this.imageView = imageView;
        this.titleView = titleView;
        this.descriptionView = descriptionView;
    }
}

   }
```

And here the RowFolderPhone.java ... showing fine, but not detecting taps:

```
public class RowFolderPhone implements RowPhone {


private final ItemPhone item;
private final LayoutInflater inflater;

public RowFolderPhone(LayoutInflater inflater, ItemPhone animal) {
    this.item = animal;
    this.inflater = inflater;
}

public View getView(View convertView) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    View view = null;

    //we have a don't have a converView so we'll have to create a new one
    if (convertView == null) {
       // ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_folder_phone, null);
        ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_folder_phone, (ViewGroup) view, false);

        //use the view holder pattern to save of already looked up subview
        holder = new ViewHolder((ImageView)viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.image),
                (TextView)viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.title));

        viewGroup.setTag(holder);

        view = viewGroup;

    } else {
        //get the holder back out
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();

        view = convertView;
    }

    //actually setup the view
    holder.imageView.setImageResource(item.getImageId());
    holder.titleView.setText(item.getName());

    return view;
}

public int getViewType() {
    return RowTypePhone.IMAGE_ROW.ordinal();
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    final ImageView imageView;
    final TextView titleView;

    private ViewHolder(ImageView imageView, TextView titleView) {
        this.imageView = imageView;
        this.titleView = titleView;
    }
  } 
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was solved by setting descendantFocusability

in : row_item_phone.xml

```
 <RelativeLayout ...
 android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

Answer (score 3):

There are something wrong with your getItem method on PhoneItemAdapter. getItem method should return list item not position. So you should replace your code to

```
public RowPhone getItem(int position) {
    return rows.get(position);
}
```

Comment: hi thanks!, i tried //return rows.get(position);
            return ((RowPhone) rows.get(position)); but not recognizing tap yet, what else could it be? cheers!

Comment: Umm... Can you show your RowPhone class code? I can't figure out any errors without more info

Comment: I just do some test with your code. There is no problems with your code. Are you sure that when 2nd row clicked and there is no output on Log? Do checking with toast is better then using log. Sometime people might confused because of no UI effects on layout.

Comment: hi, yes, no response on item, just in folder type, .( tnx!

Comment: Sorry again, can you post your RowItemPhone

Comment: hi, thanks a lot!, I have edited my post to include the RowItemPhone.java which detects taps; and RowFolderPhone.java which doesnt detect tap... cheers!